# Display error from print_r using php

Tags: php, database

Why does it display stdClass Object ( [jobid] => 1 ) stdClass Object ( [jobid] => 2 )

instead of value 1 and 2

```
<?php 
foreach($RowTable as $row) {
    print_r($row, false);?>    
}
?>
```

Comment: why do you have both while and foreach? why is the while loop outcommented?

Comment: Because that's what `$row` looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look into [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

> print_r() displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans.

if you want to print value then use `echo $row->jobid;`.